# PHP Spintax Processor

Tags: php, regex, string, spintax

I've been using the recurisve SpinTax processor as seen [here](http://www.codedevelopr.com/articles/php-spintax-function/), and it works just fine for smaller strings. However, it begins to run out of memory when the string goes beyond 20KB, and it's becoming a problem.

If I have a string like this:

```
{Hello|Howdy|Hola} to you, {Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.} {Smith|Williams|Austin}!
```

and I want to have random combinations of the words put together, and **not** use the technique as seen in the link above (recursing through the string until there are no more words in curly-braces), how should I do it?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
$array = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
        if ($v[0] == '{') {
                $n_array = explode('|', $v);
                $array[$k] = str_replace(array('{', '}'), '', $n_array[array_rand($n_array)]);
        }
}
echo implode(' ', $array);
```

But it falls apart when there are spaces in-between the options for the spintax. `RegEx` seems to be the solution here, but I have no idea how to implement it **and** have much more efficient performance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a function that uses a callback within to determine which variant of the many potentials will be created and returned:

```
// Pass in the string you'd for which you'd like a random output
function random ($str) {
    // Returns random values found between { this | and }
    return preg_replace_callback("/{(.*?)}/", function ($match) {
        // Splits 'foo|bar' strings into an array
        $words = explode("|", $match[1]);
        // Grabs a random array entry and returns it
        return $words[array_rand($words)];
    // The input string, which you provide when calling this func
    }, $str);
}

random("{Hello|Howdy|Hola} to you, {Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.} {Smith|Williams|Austin}!");
random("{This|That} is so {awesome|crazy|stupid}!");
random("{StackOverflow|StackExchange} solves all of my {problems|issues}.");
```

Comment: Thanks so much! As said in the Madara's answer's comments, this took me from memory errors to .0002590 seconds to process a 40KB file. Amazing! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_replace_callback()` to specify a replacement function.

```
$str = "{Hello|Howdy|Hola} to you, {Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.} {Smith|Williams|Austin}!";

$replacement = function ($matches) {
    $array = explode("|", $matches[1]);
    return $array[array_rand($array)];
};

$str = preg_replace_callback("/\{([^}]+)\}/", $replacement, $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Comment: I love this solution. It took .0002592 seconds to run this, and the old method got an `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 74087 bytes)` error. Excellent!

Comment: I really do appreciate this answer - it really helped. However, Johnathan Sampson got to it first. Thanks so much!